# Duplicates to close - import/export of complex numbers

Tags: discussion, questions, clean-up

I believe some of these related question should be closed, perhaps in favor of a canonical Q&A, but I do not wish to act alone:

- [Export to text file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6384/121)
- [Importing array with complex numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8198/121)
- [Exporting/Importing a Table of complex numbers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15495/121)
- [How to export a table of complex numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29549/121)
- [Complex Values in TSV](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29701/121)